# Uploading new paid version of extension license type?

Tags: extensions, licensing

We have one free version CE extension uploaded on magento connect .Now we need to upload new version as paid.Free version license is OSL.
So, What would be the license name for Custom License?
And we want to put our website's terms & condition link to "license Url" field.